# How to get rid of Series heading (column heading) using Pandas Library in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas Library, I made dictionaries that are nested in a list from file “german_words.csv”.
(for Info: “german_words.csv” is file with German words and corresponding English translated words)

german_words.csv (It's just sample, current file contains thousands of words):

```
Deutsch,English
Gedanken,thought
Stadt,city
Baum,tree
überqueren,cross
Bauernhof,farm
schwer,hard
Beginn,start
Macht,might
Geschichte,story
Säge,saw
weit,far
Meer,sea
```

Here's the code of that:

```
import pandas
import random

word_data = pandas.read_csv("./data/german_words.csv")
word_data_list = word_data.to_dict(orient="records")
print(random.choice(word_data_list))
```

And then printing random dictionary from that list.

list looks like this:

```
[{'Deutsch': 'Gedanken', 'English': 'thought'}, {'Deutsch': 'Stadt', 'English': 'city'}, {'Deutsch': 'Baum', 'English': 'tree'}, ....]
```

Here's the sample output:

```
{'Deutsch': 'Küste', 'English': 'coast'}
```

But the problem is, I don't want the *column heading* in the dictionaries.

I want these dictionaries in list as follows:

```
[{'Gedanken': 'thought'}, {'Stadt': 'city'}, {'Baum': 'tree'} ...]
```

Comment: What are the columns of `word_data`? Please write a sample of code so that we can reproduce a similar `word_data`, with for instance `word_data = pd.DataFrame(data=...)`

Comment: `dict(df.values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Series` by column `Deutsch` like index, select column `English` and then convert to dictionaries:

```
print (word_data.set_index('Deutsch')['English'].to_dict())
```

Or if only 2 columns `DataFrame` is possible use:

```
print (dict(word_data.to_numpy()))
```

EDIT: For list of dictionaries use:

```
print([{x["Deutsch"]: x["English"]} for x in word_data.to_dict(orient="records")])

[{'Gedanken': 'thought'}, {'Stadt': 'city'}, {'Baum': 'tree'},
 {'überqueren': 'cross'}, {'Bauernhof': 'farm'}, {'schwer': 'hard'},
 {'Beginn': 'start'}, {'Macht': 'might'}, {'Geschichte': 'story'}, 
 {'Säge': 'saw'}, {'weit': 'far'}, {'Meer': 'sea'}]
```

Comment: I would like to have output as dictionaries in a list. I just edited the post.

Comment: @yashviradia - answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

word_data = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Deutsch": ["Gedanken", "Stadt", "Baum"],
        "English": ["thought", "city", "tree"],
    }
)

print({d["Deutsch"]: d["English"] for d in word_data.to_dict(orient="records")})
# {'Gedanken': 'thought', 'Stadt': 'city', 'Baum': 'tree'}
```

Comment: I would like to have output as dictionaries in a list. I just edited the post.